# Not Able to add some override method in Dialog class in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have created a class that extends Dialog class. And in this class I want to add "Location Change" code in this class. When I try to do the same it shows me 2 problem

1. One is method does not override it super class
2. Wrong 1st argument type: Found: 'android.context.Context', required: 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'

Now code for the same

```
public class DialogChooseYourLocation extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {


private Location mylocation;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private final static int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS = 0x1;
private final static int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 0x2;

Double latitude;
Double longitude;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setUpGClient();
}
```

// getting error here : Wrong 1st argument type: Found: 'android.context.Context', required: 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'

```
private synchronized void setUpGClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .enableAutoManage(getContext(), 0, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}
```

// getting error : One is method does not override it super class

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mylocation = location;
    if (mylocation != null) {
        latitude = mylocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = mylocation.getLongitude();
        Log.e("TAG", "onLocationChanged: " + "Latitude : " + latitude + "Longitude : " + longitude);
        GeoLocation();
        //Or Do whatever you want with your location
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    getMyLocation();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void checkPermissions() {
    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getOwnerActivity(),
                    listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    } else {
        getMyLocation();
    }

}
```

// getting error : One is method does not override it super class

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        getMyLocation();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In `enableAutoManage` method wrong 1st argument type:-
This method expects first parameter as an reference of FragmentActivit but you have passed reference of Context. So there are two solution. Either you have to extend `FragmentActivity` to your class `DialogChooseYourLocation`  and pass the reference of your class as an first argument in `enableAutoManage` method. Or you can simply remove `enableAutoManage` method and manually handle `connect/disconnect` as shown below.

```
@Override
private synchronized void setUpGClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

`onLocationChanged` method does not override it super class:-
Just check which LocationListener you are importing. There are 2 different LocationListener. `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` and `android.location.LocationListener`. You should use `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`

`onRequestPermissionsResult` method does not override it super class:-
Your class `DialogChooseYourLocation` does not implement [ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html), so it does not have the `onRequestPermissionsResult` to override. 
When you call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`, it is that parentActivity that is receiving a callback to `onRequestPermissionsResult`, it won't automatically call any method in your `DialogChooseYourLocation`. You'll need to manually pass the information from the Activity's onRequestPermissionsResult to your `DialogChooseYourLocation`.